# Eclipse RCP and Jython

Tags: eclipse, pydev, jython, rcp

I'm writing an eclipse RCP application and want to integrate Jython with it.
I'm already able to launch the pydev python console using the Console view and choosing PyDev -> Python console.
But when trying to launch Jython I get a series of exceptions:
[image: Launching Jython]

Jython does work in my Eclipse but not in my Eclipse application.

This is what I get:

```java
!SESSION 2015-05-07 10:53:51.497 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product AvgPowerTool.product
Command-line arguments:  -product AvgPowerTool.product -data /nfs/iil/proj/dt/sdq06/dmhadar/avg-power-tool/dts_cct_e_explore-avgpowertool/../runtime-AvgPowerTool.product -dev file:/nfs/iil/proj/dt/sdq06/dmhadar/avg-power-tool/dts_cct_e_explore-avgpowertool/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/AvgPowerTool.product/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2015-05-07 10:53:53.939
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.python.pydev.shared_core 4 4 2015-05-07 10:54:19.664
!MESSAGE Unexpected error connecting to console.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unexpected error connecting to console.
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.sayHello(PydevConsoleFactory.java:156)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.access$0(PydevConsoleFactory.java:136)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory$1.run(PydevConsoleFactory.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: <type 'org.xml.sax.SAXException'>:org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
Command Line used:  "Internal Jython process (no command line)"

Environment:
null
at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleCommunication.hello(PydevConsoleCommunication.java:768)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.sayHello(PydevConsoleFactory.java:145)
... 3 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.python.pydev.debug 4 4 2015-05-07 10:54:19.667
!MESSAGE Unexpected error connecting to console.
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: <type 'org.xml.sax.SAXException'>:org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
Command Line used:  "Internal Jython process (no command line)"

Environment:
null
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleCommunication.hello(PydevConsoleCommunication.java:768)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.sayHello(PydevConsoleFactory.java:145)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.access$0(PydevConsoleFactory.java:136)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory$1.run(PydevConsoleFactory.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.python.pydev.debug 4 4 2015-05-07 10:54:19.670
!MESSAGE Error initializing console.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Unexpected error connecting to console.
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.sayHello(PydevConsoleFactory.java:156)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.access$0(PydevConsoleFactory.java:136)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory$1.run(PydevConsoleFactory.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: <type 'org.xml.sax.SAXException'>:org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
Command Line used:  "Internal Jython process (no command line)"

Environment:
null
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleCommunication.hello(PydevConsoleCommunication.java:768)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.sayHello(PydevConsoleFactory.java:145)
    ... 3 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.python.pydev.debug 4 4 2015-05-07 10:54:19.670
!MESSAGE Unexpected error connecting to console.
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: <type 'org.xml.sax.SAXException'>:org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
Command Line used:  "Internal Jython process (no command line)"

Environment:
null
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleCommunication.hello(PydevConsoleCommunication.java:768)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.sayHello(PydevConsoleFactory.java:145)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.access$0(PydevConsoleFactory.java:136)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory$1.run(PydevConsoleFactory.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

In my imported packages I have `org.python.pydev.core` and `org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `xerces` library, try including them in your classpath